# What is a broken label?

Tags: windows, batch-file, label, comments

Further to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57208876/add-prefix-to-filenames-using-batch-files?noredirect=1#comment100928231_57208876), I need to ask why is it bad (as in results and practice) to have `::` comment instead of `REM` within code blocks:

```
for %%a in (*.pdf) do (
:: This bad, but why?
)
```

Can someone explain this to me? And thereby restore my faith in batch files!

Comment: That would be Phase 2. [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/2152082). Get a cup of coffee, it's really hard stuff.

Comment: @Stephan I'm all out of coffee, I'm scared ;). Thanks for the link!

Comment: Some explanations, see [Unexpected “The system cannot find the drive specified.” in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19847135/463115)

Answer (score 3):

The reason that it's a *broken* label can be demonstrated by this code:

```dos
@ECHO On
SETLOCAL
GOTO fred
ECHO miss this 1
:fred
GOTO :bill
ECHO miss this 2
:bill
GOTO ::charlie
echo miss this 3
::charlie
ECHO all done!
GOTO :EOF
```

That is, a leading `:` indicates a label, but the label-name itself may not start `:`. Now whether `:label:with:colons` is a valid label, I'll leave to the enthusiastic experimenter. I'd prefer to keep to a simple rule - no colons in label-names.

As for the no-labels-in-code-blocks rule, remember `cmd`'s history. At one time, code-blocks were not allowed. It's a simple-minded processor which may have learned a lot since its inception. It wants to maintain backward-compatibility, so suppose we come across some common constructions within a block:

goto label, goto :label, call label, call :label

this leaves us with a nightmare of possible return-paths and interpretation possibilities. Does `goto outofblock` terminate the block? Does `goto inblock` terminate the iteration?

Hence, the simple-minded rule, no labels in blocks. I remember *jeb* worked out a set of rules where labels *can* be used, which was interesting. Here's [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kyU2pGWA6Jc)